# Add percentage to number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

How can I add a percentage to a number in Ruby?

In this example I want to add `20%` to `32.92`:

```
irb(main):001:0> 32.92 * (1 + (20 / 100))
=> 32.92
```

Google answers with the correct answer; `39.50`.

Answer (score 6):

Lets say your base_value is: **39.92**.
Your markup is **20**.

Integer division will lead to the following:

```rb
20 / 100
# => 0
```

So irb is the right direction. This gives better results:

```rb
20.to_f / 100
# => 0.2
```

So the final calculation will look like this:

```rb
final_value = (base_value + (markup.to_f / 100) * base_value).round
```

This gives you the expected value.

As you don’t mind the result to be floored instead of rounded it’s possible to get correct result using integer division:

```rb
final_value = base_value + base_value * markup / 100
```

Answer (score 5):

`20 / 100` returns `0`, because it's integer division if you pass integers as arguments. Instead, you can pass floats, like this:

```
32.92 * (1 + (20.0 / 100.0))
```

or do simply:

```
32.92 * 1.2
```

Comment: If I run `(32.92 * (1 + (20.0 / 100.0))).round(2)` in `irb` then it works but when `32.92` is a variable being read from a CSV file I get `undefined method 'round' for "72.28":String`?

Comment: If you read CSV content, it's mapped as strings by default. You have to explicitly convert it to something meaningful, like `Float`.